# How to type sftp password with '$' in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, curl, sftp

I need to write python script that periodically sends files over SFTP to remote server. I used Popen class to execute Linux commands from the python script because I want to check later if the transfer was successful.

The script works OK, but the problem is that my SFTP password ends with `'$$$'`, and `'$'`seems to be some special character in Linux?

The command I call from Popen is:

```
curl -s -S -T ./file.txt sftp://username:paswwordwith$$$@ip_address
```

I am getting an error regarding the password. From the error message I can see that password `'$$$'` is interpreted as some number...

How can I type the password correctly?

Comment: Could you paste your `popen` command? `$` should only be a problem if you do `shell=True`.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` begins a shell variable reference in most shells. Enclose the last argument in single quotes and it should work.

Edit: David Ehrmann's comment is correct; I'd overlooked the Popen part. However, the fact that you pasted it all as one string leads me to suspect that you are indeed using `shell=True`. In this situation I would use a list of arguments and leave `shell` at the default of `False`.

Comment: Single quotes fixed the problem. Thank you. However, now I am getting  error message: Upload failed: permission denied :( With Filezilla I can upload files without problems, but this command fails to do that.